# Java LinkedList remove

Tags: java, linked-list

fast question.If I remove element from LinkedList like this

```
playerDeck.remove(0);
```

or like this

```
playerDeck.removeFirst();
```

does first element of list will be empty space? or all list slide to up and first element will be the one who was second?
example:
Linked list:

```
4
5
6
8
```

after remove 4, list it will be

```
null
5
6
8
```

or ?

```
5
6
8
```

Comment: The list would be the latter.

Comment: Couldn't you have *tried* this in a shorter space of time than it took you to write the question?

Comment: You just felt like chatting with Jon Skeet, admit it :)

Comment: And yes you should feel honoured...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would be no "empty space", no `null`. This is the general contract for all lists (`List<E>`) in Java Collections API.

Answer (score 0):

This is code for it. You must attach source with your IDE.

```
 private E remove(Entry<E> e) {
    if (e == header)
        throw new NoSuchElementException();

        E result = e.element;
    e.previous.next = e.next;
    e.next.previous = e.previous;
        e.next = e.previous = null;
        e.element = null;
    size--;
    modCount++;
        return result;
    }
```

I hope you understand its logic

Comment: Why declare it `private`?

Comment: because its public interfaces are  public E removeFirst(),public boolean remove(Object o) and others in LinkedList